# Splitting a string into a list of numbers

Tags: python, list

The following block of code was tested on python 2.

```
    A="1 2 10"
    A=raw_input.split()
    print A
```

This prints a list with 4 numbers(splitting the 10 into 1 and 0),

Why does this happen?

Comment: @omri Default delimiter is any whitespace character

Comment: @omri_saadon, he use Python 2 not 3

Comment: and his code is correct

Comment: He just forget parenthese after raw_input,

Comment: `raw_input().split()`

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal split

```
B = A.split()
```

Comment: This will act the exact same as not putting a parameter for the given input

Comment: True, I edited.

Comment: I see anything diffrent, heve you considered this answer